# Ubuntu 20.04 on External Disk suddenly stop booting - load GRUB terminal

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, usb-drive

Since quite some time ago I had an Ubuntu 18.x installed on an [external disk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07PXCYCX1) that I would use when I wanted to work from my own laptop instead of booting up the cumbersome and slow office laptop. This laptop would have 2 internal SSD, one with Windows and one that I would use to install games, store large files etc.

Installing Ubuntu on an external drive would allow me to simply plug in the USB SSD and be in a development environment with everything I needed.

I've recently (2-3 months ago) run a fresh format of that USB SSD and installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 and everything worked as before.

Now, this morning I've attached the USB SSD as usual, pressed F7 on the computer boot to bring up the UEFI list of OS and select Ubuntu... but I've been greeted by a GRUB terminal.

The weird thing is that running a simple `ls` didn't list the USB SSD at all. First thing I thought was that somehow the USB SSD, that had zero issue until yesterday, was dead but then I decided to try something.

I've had an [USB Hub](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BWF5U0M/) laying around that I had bought to be able to connect multiple controllers when i wanted to play with the kids and decided to try and connect the USB SSD through one of those ports instead of directly via the laptop USB.

I restarted with the USB SSD connected via the USB Hub and now GRUB terminal comes up anyway but if I run an `ls` I can see the external disk being mounted properly and visible.

I made an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS live disk to try and run the Grub Repair utility and after booting it up I got confirmation again that if I connect the USB SSD directly to the USB port, it's not detected, but if, **in the same port**, I connect the USB Hub and then the USB SSD to that, it gets detected.

I'm honestly baffled and spent the entire day trying to figure this out. Unfortunately I can't even think of what to search on google, hence why I am here.

To conclude, I've run the grub repair but all that I've obtained is that now, on boot, I've to press F6 (instead of F7 for some reason) to bring up the OS boot list and there is Windows, as before, but then 2 "Ubuntu", one of which still is showing up the grub terminal, and the new one that loads up my Ubuntu USB SSD but only if it's connected via the USB Hub.

Can anyone make head or tail of this situation? What the heck happened? How can I "clean up" this mess? I mean I could just keep using the USB Hub even if that is slowing down my Ubuntu as the cable is most probably working at a lower speed than the direct USB SSD cable but I'd really like to understand what is going on here.

Comment: What brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair If booting an "ubuntu" entry that would be from an internal drive's ESP. All external drives directly boot using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and in UEFI are shown as UEFI:XXXX where XXX may be label of external drive or PMAP. You just may have an old "ubuntu" entry in UEFI?

Comment: The laptop is a custom build from pcspecialist UK. Here are the laptop specs: http://i.mypcspecs.io/cc22e3c6a722be3df331bc22b7c7c99c.jpg. I'll go through your suggestion tomorrow morning as it's evening now and I need to spend some time with the kids :)

Comment: @guiverc running `lsb_release -a` return `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` in the description. I'll update the question now with this detail. Live disk is from the 22.04.

Comment: @oldfred I didn't get all the info you wrote in there. I'd appreciate a little more details in what I should check/try. This is a boot-repair info dump: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dmqSsFTybv/

Comment: about having an "old entry" for ubuntu, I doubt it could be the case as, as I mention, everything was working fine literally the day before.

Comment: FYI:  18.10 is in the same *full development* cycle as 20.04; the cycle starts at the first non-LTS after the prior LTS, contains 3 non-LTS releases and the final LTS release.. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the *full dev cycle* that started with Ubuntu 20.10  (18.x isn't that helpful; as 18.10 is the same cycle as 20.04, 18.04 from the prior cycle..)

Comment: It is possible that there is hardware problem, for example the case that the computer can no longer provide enough power via USB, but you have external power supply to the hub. It is also possible (and maybe most probable) that there is some software problem. The problem might be located either internally in the computer or in the SSD with Ubuntu. It can sometimes be difficult to see how UEFI boots (and remove possible distractors to make your Ubuntu system work correctly again in the office computer). - In the future, please consider using a full backup of the SSD for example via Clonezilla.

Comment: Install basically looks normal. Just you have MBR (msdos) partitions on external drive. Ubuntu allows that, but Windows requires gpt and UEFI strongly suggests gpt. That should not prevent boot. While line 246 has correct UUID the suggested root of hd0 is probably not correct. Your NVMe drives would be first. But since UUID is correct I would expect it to boot. When you get grub> can you boot with `configfile (hd0,1)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but change hd0 to hd2 or hd2. From `ls`, then `ls (hd2,1)/` do you see install? that would confirm which drive  hd0,hd1 or hd2 is correct.

Comment: Just to add more info, at boot I can see a lot of errors about not finding partitions and devices now (graphic card etc). Also, now the wi-fi card is not detected anymore. The absolutely ridiculous thing is that everything works flawlessly from Windows. At this point I'd like just to be able to reset the boot menu and get rid of all the Ubuntu entries so I can start clean with a new installation eventually.